# Show week number in gnome-calendar

Tags: gnome-calendar

Is there a possibility to show the week numbers in gnome-calendar? I'm using version 3.28.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I can seem to find answers only for the same question, but concerning the calendar that drops down from the top bar in GNOME Shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature isn't available in gnome-calendar but you can ask this feature on the gitlab page of the project: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/issues

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, and for pointing me to the relevant place.